# Second floor washer drain pipe sticks out from the floor. Should I be concerned?

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine, washer, drains

[image][image][image][image]I am having a washer and dryer delivered soon. Wondering if I need to have the washer drain recessed, or is it fine protruding from the floor about 2 inches? This is the way it was when I purchased the home recently. All the photos I've googled, show the floor drain flush with the floor. How will the washer sit over it and not damage it since it's not recessed? Another concern is the large opening around the pipe. Should it look like that? Do I need to have it fixed?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How close is the drain to the wall?

Comment: Hey Jack, thanks. The drain is 11.5" from the back wall and 13 3/8" from the side wall. Based on a previous answer by another user, it may not be a concern at all. But, it looks like it's improperly installed, considering the protrusion and big gaps around it. If it needs to be redone, I just need to have it done asap before washer install. Thank you again.

Comment: That appears to be a drain for the overflow tray - where's the actual standpipe for the washer drain? in the wall-box with the supply valves?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, that drain stub is for attaching to a plastic drain pan.  It is left stubbed up high because they don't know how you are going to attach it and cutting off extra pipe is much easier than adding more.

Most pans I've bought come with a glue-on fitting that you seal into a hole you drill in the pan.

[image]

Additionally, you don't need to worry about the big hole.  That is there to give you a little bit of play for installation and will be covered up by the washer pan when installed.  As long as the pan does its job and the drain fitting is tightened, nothing will leak down that hole.

Comment: I thought about having a drain pan, but wasn't sure with the height of the pipe. I've added a pic now. I would love to add more, but not sure how to add more than one. Thank you Chris.

Comment: Excellent.  From the picture, you already have the drain fitting - probably from a previous owner's pan?  All you need now is the pan itself and a hole saw to make the hole.  I'm assuming there might be some play in the height of the pipe because that pan will be flush to the floor when a heavy washer is on top of it.

Comment: Yes, definitely was a drain pan there previously. The seller tossed it. I do plan on adding a new one. I'm new to all this, but with the proper guidance, I feel confident I can get it done, thanks!